# Firefox DevTools: Tabs & How to keep debugger files open after page reload/refresh? (Stop auto close)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

When I am debugging javascript in [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) DevTools, and I refresh /reload the page, it just closes the file I had open and starts blank. This is a waste of time.

1) How can I make it perform like Chrome DevTools which preserves the file and exact line location in the file even after reloading?

2) Where are file tabs in firefox debugger tools? It seems there's only a list of ALL files loaded on the page, and I have to hunt down the files one by one after each page reload. Chrome has file tabs in the debugger which persist after reload. Where are tabs in firefox's debugger?

Answer (score 2):

That the wrong file is selected after a page reload is obviously a bug in the Firefox DevTools - which only happens in some cases, btw. - so I've filed this as [bug 1283792](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283792) .

Support for having multiple files open at the same time is not implemented yet. It is requested (by one of the main DevTools developers) in [bug 1097706](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1097706).

**Update:**

Opening multiple files at the same time is supported in the reworked debugger UI currently available by setting `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) to `true` (and enabled by default in Firefox Developer Edition and Nightly).

Comment: I hope they get these bugs/features fixed and added soon. They will make firefox development MUCH better for JS